# How to get average of column in sql nested query with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to calculate average of "final" column for symbol for a particular date and id , here id is primary column date is unique colum, currently I am using below query

```
select   s1.id, avg_final(s1.date,s1.symbol,5) as short_vg 
from final_data s1 where s1.date = p_date;
```

Above query is a part of a procedure, and  p_date is input to procedure, here I want to remove function "avg_final" which is taking long time,

Below function need to remove:

```
             DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS avg_final;
             CREATE FUNCTION avg_final(p_date datetime,p_symbol
             varchar(50),avg_int INT) RETURNS decimal(20,2)
             BEGIN
                DECLARE income decimal(20,2);
                select avg(dd.final_value) into income from
                (select  * from final_data a where a.symbol = p_symbol and a.date
             <= p_date order by a.date desc limit avg_int) dd;
               RETURN income;
             END;
```

I have tried below query it needs proper correlation between sub
queries , after running this it throws error for v.symbol

```
select
 (
  select
    (select s.id from final_data s where s.date = max(asd.date)
and s.symbol = asd.symbol) as maxid,  avg(asd.final_value) as avg_val
from
    (select sd.* from final_data sd where sd.symbol=v.symbol and
sd.id = v.id order by date desc limit 5) asd ) from final_data v.
```

(I am using Mysql)

Below is sample data and expected avg_final value:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|id    |  final_value | date              |  symbol |   avg_final|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |  20.00       |1/1/2014 0:00:00   |  MUMBAI |87          |
|2     |  55.00       |1/1/2014 0:00:00   |  DELHI  |33          |
|3     |  30.00       |1/2/2014 0:00:00   |  MUMBAI |            |
|4     |  15.00       |1/2/2014 0:00:00   |  DELHI  |            |
|5     |  40.00       |1/3/2014 0:00:00   |  MUMBAI |            |
|6     |  45.00       |1/4/2014 0:00:00   |  MUMBAI |            |
|7     |  60.00       |1/3/2014 0:00:00   |  DELHI  |            |
|8     |  300.00      |1/5/2014 0:00:00   |  MUMBAI |            |
|9     |  30.00       |1/4/2014 0:00:00   |  DELHI  |            |
|10    |  5.00        |1/5/2014 0:00:00   |  DELHI  |            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sample data is also shown in image

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here I want to remove avg_final function from select query, If I copy and paste functions select statement in first select query then it is throwing me error-- Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'v.symbol' in 'where clause'